# How to set Content-Encoding metadata headers with webpack compression?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, gzip

I love `npm run watch` but my uncompressed bundle is 7.5MB. I'm also tunneling it through ngrok for HTTPS usage (and team usage). So it takes quite a while to do a simple page reload to check if a CSS update worked as expected.

It would be really nice if I could serve a gzipped version during development... But whenever I create `app.js.gz`locally, the metadata headers don't get set correctly.

On AWS S3, I can easily set the headers: `Content-Encoding: gzip` and `Content-Type: text/javascript`

Through the S3 bucket, those metadata headers tell the browser to inflate the file and then the site renders correctly.

However I am trying to do this locally without S3 so I don't have to wait for upload times. So how can I set this metadata? With webpack? With Apache? Other?

I am using a Laravel back-end and React-Redux front-end with `compression-webpack-plugin`

Here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new CompressionPlugin({
                filename: '[path].gz[query]',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.svg$/,
                threshold: 10240,
                minRatio: 0.8,
            }),
        ],
    });
```

Without the correct metadata headers, the browser doesn't know to inflate the gzipped file so I just get a console error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: hi..did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible:

```js
const BrotliPlugin = require('brotli-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin")
```

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js) file as a sample. It applies minification and compression (both gzip and Brotli) for production builds but this can be changed.

Comment: Nice! I'm already using compresssion-webpack-plugin, but how can I use it in development mode?

Comment: In the sample you would achieve that by changing (e.g. commenting out) line 136 to ensure webpack uses the compression plugin in both development and production. You can use the sample code to modify your `webpack.config.js` that I assume is triggered by `npm run watch`.

Comment: I have updated my question as I have realized that the problem is that the metadata headers aren't being set correctly. The gzipped file was already being created each time. It was just the Content-Encoding and Content-Type headers that are missing. Do you know how to set this @winwiz1?

Comment: It is the browser who indicates first it supports compression and states the particular types of compression it is willing to accept. Then the webserver serves it if it can. At the server side it's best not to spend time on setting http headers and let middleware do it as a part of what effectively is a simple 2-way compression negotiation. For Express all that is done by [express-static-gzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip) middleware. Sample usage: search for "expressStaticGzip" in [this](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/src/srv/server.ts) file.